# Filter data based on some fields in Kibana Dashboard using URL

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am using the .net application and using iframe to show the kibana dashboard. So just had control over URL to show the data on Kibana dashboard.

http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/Name-Dashboard?embed=true&_g=(time:(from:now-6M,mode:quick,to:now),title:'Name%20Dashboard')

Now i want to filter the dashboard based on some application logic. So user will be shown data based on his settings. So need to add some query or filter to URL mentioned above. I checked the documentation for elastic search and there is provision for adding the query parameters from URL

http://localhost:9200/indexname/type/_search?q=field:fieldValue

But how I can add the query string in kibana so that the values will be passed to elastic search and dashboard is shown appropriately

Comment: In Kibana Dashboard,You can pass queries in search which is in Discover tab.link [] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html

Comment: Sorry. That is already setup. What I want is to filter at run time on top of what is step up.

Comment: Setup the dashboard in kibana manually and examine the URL.  I don't think they've documented the format, but you're sure to see your queries and filters there.

Comment: Thanks Alain. Yes I am not able to find documentation details. The issue is that i checked kibana logs and can see the URL. But filter is based on visualization and visualization on search. I want to show some data on dashboard based on setting so need to filter dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

http://localhost:5601/#/dashboard/Name-Dashboard?embed=true&_g=(time:(from:now-6M,mode:quick,to:now),title:'Name%20Dashboard')&_a=(query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'Field1:Value1)))

using _a query parameter we can add the filter

Comment: With this syntax, I have an `Unable to parse URL` error. Is it still available or is there a new syntax?