# Embed Kibana Dashboard in the website that dynamically takes value depending on customer id

Tags: kibana, dashboard, kibana-5, kibana-7

I am new to Kibana and working on a project where I have to integrate a dynamic dashboard in the website for every user in the system.
Is there any way that I can achieve this on Kibana?

- I tried passing the query using the iframe code, but the issue with that is If any user tries using the filter option they can see the data of the other user using the filter.
- I tried not passing the filter option, however, this is not a good approach, as I want the user to filter and see only through their data.

These are the links that I referred to but didn't find any optimal solution

1. [Filter data based on some fields in Kibana Dashboard using URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148142/filter-data-based-on-some-fields-in-kibana-dashboard-using-url)
2. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-embedding-dashboard-in-website-with-dynamic-filter-param/241518/2

This [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/embedding-dashboard-in-website-with-dynamic-filter-param/120510) describes exactly what I want to achieve.

1. I need to know how to pass URL filters dynamically so I can show each customer only their dashboard data based on the customer_id field or other fields.
2. Also how to remove the topbar add a filter so they can create their own filters
3. And how to hide/remove the loading kibana picture while it is loading so users don't know we are using kibana as Whitelabel.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: you should probably configure security/spaces as even without the filter toolbar you can manipulate the url https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html